# Goodbye Mod team, I'm a mere mortal again

Tags: discussion, moderators

**First, the tl;dr:** Starting today, I am no longer a community moderator on Super User.

Over the past weeks, I've made the decision to step down as a moderator. I was [elected on July 24, 2012](https://superuser.com/election/2), and it's been a bit more than three years that I've been part of an awesome moderator team. Countless flags have been handled since then, and many discussions have been made here, on Meta.

I was—and still am—very enthusiastic to lead this community by example, providing guidance to new and old members alike, with the goal to make this site the number one resource for finding help to any kind of computer issue people may have. At the same time, being a moderator allowed me to learn how to *communicate* online, how to encourage, to arbitrate, to guide.

However, in the last months I've noticed that my personal circumstances changed. Not for worse—quite the contrary. I've moved places, started a new job, and I'm pursuing a PhD in computer science. But at the same time, these circumstances just do not allow me to invest the time I personally think is necessary for me to keep up to date with what's going on at Super User, our users—our *community*—and Stack Exchange at large. This is why I've resigned. I just could not handle as many flags as I think were needed. I just could not follow what was going on. I felt like I lost touch with the community in general. Simply because there was too little time I could spend.

It's important to mention that there has been absolutely no pressure whatsoever from my fellow moderators or the Stack Exchange community team. There has been no dispute that caused this. Some might think there are expectations for moderators to handle *X* flags every month, destroy *Y* spammers, and close *Z* posts. Some might even have those expectations (although I've yet to find this person). You could argue that I stepped back because I could not fulfill those expectations. But it's not like that.

There's a lot of respect for the work all of us volunteers do, and it's fine if moderators don't contribute as much as others, or as much as they used to at some point. This was a purely personal decision, because I think I cannot live up to *my own* standards that I set over those past years.

I'm leaving the mod team and giving the diamond back, but I will continue to be a regular user. I'll be happy to edit posts, answer questions, and occasionally track down spammers, if time allows to. I don't see myself ever leaving this community, for I've learned so much from it—and there's still much more to learn.

With this I want to thank every community member for their support, for their contributions, which make this site one of my absolute favorite places on the Internet. And of course,  a warm-hearted *Thank You!* to all of the other mods, who will continue to lead the SU community: Daniel, Ivo, Journeyman Geek, Mokubai, Nathan, Oliver, random, Sathya, and studiohack.

I will see you around!

<3

Comment: Man you'll be sorely missed in the Mod dept, esp wrt tracking down chain spammers, sockpuppets and crazy levels of edits . best wishes in your future endeavors :)

Comment: It's weird to see your name without the diamond, you've pretty much had it my entire career here and you've always been a "lead by example" type mod. Congrats and good luck on your new endeavors!

Comment: Would you edit in "♦" to your username? (At the end of it, as it used to be since 2K12)

Comment: Should I upvote or downvote? :-(

Comment: I second what everyone has already written.  You did an exemplary job as a moderator.  Best of luck moving onward and upward.

Comment: @RogUE that character can't be entered in usernames.

Comment: Missing you already, slhck. Wishing you all the best and don't forget to say hello! Please let me know if I can ever be of assistance!

Comment: Hats off to you (all of those collected in the Winter Bash).

Comment: tl;dr = "too long; didn't read".  You say the post is too long for *yourself*? So why you wrote it so long? Or why you used "tl;dr"? Anyway, thanks for your mod service!

Comment: @miroxlav No, it's not too long for me—it's actually rather concise for what I had in mind. "tl;dr" is something that people usually say (ironically) to summarize a post for those who may not want to read it in its entirety. And thank you!

Comment: @slhck, thanks for all your help, you will be missed. I wish you the best in all your endeavours!

Peace

Comment: Thanks for all the hard work, slhck!

Comment: Really good question!

Comment: OMG, a PhD (Pretty hard Degree) you will barely have time to eat!

Comment: Ah... I didn't know this but now do—you used to be a mod—seems appropriate for sure with all your contributions. I must have joined right after you left or started paying attention sometime afterward at who the mods were on SU. One question though, how's the degree coming along man?

Comment: @McDonald's Thanks, I'm slowly getting there … it's crazy how time flies. Doing your PhD in Germany usually takes about 3–5 years.

Answer (score 53):

slhck is an awesome person, was an awesome mod, and his contributions to the community will be remembered and endure for a very long time, helping countless other users fix their temperamental broken software.... *especially* `ffmpeg`. ;-)

He also helped *me* grow as a person and as a community member during my formative first few months on SU.

Looking forward to continued `ffmpeg` answers from slhck while he pursues his PhD.

Thanks, man. Can we call you "Dr. slhck" when you get your plaque? ;-)

Comment: Thank you. I remember a few discussions where we may not have always agreed, but they were definitely worth it. I'll happily continue to read your well-reasoned Meta posts. (And yes, you may call me that, but that's gonna be at least another three years from now, I guess, heh.)

Comment: @slhck Your `ffmpeg` answers were well written and easy to follow. If you find the time make sure to stop by once in a while. The questions never end! Just curious—will the PhD involve multimedia?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Thanks. I will, when I find some time. Thanks for helping out on those ffmpeg questions. And yes, it does, it's about finding out how people behave when they use web TV and streaming services in the presence of poor delivery or audiovisual quality. A bit of behavioral psychology mixed with technical influence factors.

Comment: So I think its the time to call you `Dr. slhck` @slhck.

Answer (score 24):

It hurts my eyes to see the letters “slhck ” without the little rhombus (a.k.a. diamond) after them — but better that than to have you disappear altogether.  Thanks for your service, and good luck with your “personal circumstances”.

Answer (score 15):

I remember you were one of our more active mods, but your activity has been down recently and it's sad to see you give up the diamond. You've been very helpful to the community as well as to me personally, and I do owe you a significant debt for your work.

slhck, good luck on your future endeavors, and I hope you continue to contribute to this site. We miss you as a mod.

Answer (score 14):

You don't know me but I know you; because you helped me a lot without with your answers.
And I'm not the only person like that.
Let me thank you by the name of all unknown users for the huge work you have done here.
Men, helping people without knowing them is something that few people can do!
And you did it day by day, night by night, making SU better and better place for all of us.

Thank you for the heroic job you have done. Thank you for your answers. Thank you.
Hope `FFMpeg` tag will stay alive ;) Hope to see you ♦ again!